# How can I programmatically rotate all the pages in a PDF using native macOS tools?

Tags: terminal, applescript, pdf

Given a file path, I need to rotate all the pages in a PDF at that file path using nothing that isn't included with macOS. The wrapper for this will be AppleScript, so I also have access to the command line and therefore all of the scripting languages installed by default with macOS, but nothing that would require `brew` or, for example, Python's `pip`.

Comment: This posting at [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/1026213/rotate-all-pages-of-pdf-from-command-line-in-os-x/1026237) may provide some help.

Comment: @icondaemon doesn’t this require additional software?

Comment: Can I suggest you [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/302799/edit) your question to include what version of macOS you're running? Also, can you clarify how you need the pages rotated (e.g. 90° clockwise or...)? Finally, would a solution involving Automator be acceptable, or one involving JavaScript for Automation (JXA)?

Comment: @patrix - true. I spent a few days last year trying to find native PDF manipulation tools available from the command line and found only 16 automations in /System/Library/Automator, but none that do what the OP needs, as he has probably figured out himself. Automator has a Rotate Images function for Preview, but I don't think that works on PDF files.

Comment: I'm looking into automator's `Split PDF`, `Rotate Images` (or an AppleScript I have which will work on single-page PDFs), and `Combine PDF Pages`. Those might get the job done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge **macOS** does not have *any one native command line Unix executable* that can *rotate all pages* in a **PDF** (while keeping text based ones text based). `sip` can rotate a single page **PDF** however the resulting **PDF** is an *encapsulated image*, not *text* if it was text base to begin with. Also, not sure if there is a way with just *plain* **AppleScript**, other then via **UI Scripting** the *default* **Preview** application, without going to **AppleScriptObjC** (**Cocoa-AppleScript**) and or **Python**, etc.

Using *third-party command line utilities* is probably the easiest, but you said it has to be done only using what's *a default part of* **macOS**. So, I'll offer an **AppleScript** solution that uses **UI Scripting** the *default* **Preview** application, that can be used in the event there isn't another way with **AppleScriptObjC** or without *third-party utilities*, etc.

This solution, as offered (and coded), assumes that **Preview** is the *default* application for **PDF** documents and uses it to *rotate* all the pages in the **PDF** document. It is also setup as an **Automator** *workflow*. (Although there are other ways to incorporate the AppleScript *code* shown below.)

First, in **Finder**, make a copy of the target **PDF** documents and work with those.

In **Automator**, create a new *workflow* document, adding the following *actions*:

- **Get Specified Finder Items**

  - *Add* the copied target **PDF** document to this *action*.
- **Run AppleScript Script**

  - *Replace* the *default code* with the *code* below:

**AppleScript *code*:**

```
on run {input}
    set thisLong to 0.25 -- # The value of 'thisLong' is decimal seconds delay between keystrokes, adjust as necessary.
    set theRotation to "r" -- # Valid values are 'l' or 'r' for Rotate Left or Rotate Right.
    set theViewMenuCheckedList to {}
    set theMenuItemChecked to missing value
    repeat with thisItem in input
        tell application "Finder" to open file thisItem -- # By default, in this use case, the PDF file will open in Preview.
        delay 1 --  # Adjust as necessary. This is the only 'delay' not defined by the value of 'thisLong'.
        tell application "System Events"
            perform action "AXRaise" of window 1 of application process "Preview" -- # Just to make sure 'window 1' is front-most.
            delay thisLong
            --  # Ascertain which of the first six 'View' menu items is checked.
            set theViewMenuCheckedList to (value of attribute "AXMenuItemMarkChar" of menu items 1 thru 6 of menu 1 of menu bar item 5 of menu bar 1 of application process "Preview")
            repeat with i from 1 to 6
                if item i in theViewMenuCheckedList is not missing value then
                    set theMenuItemChecked to i as integer
                    exit repeat
                end if
            end repeat
            --  # Process keystrokes based on which 'View' menu item is checked.
            --  # This is being done so the subsequent keystroke ⌘A 'Select All' 
            --  # occurs on the 'Thumbnails', not the body of the document.
            if theMenuItemChecked is not 2 then
                repeat with thisKey in {"2", "1", "2"}
                    keystroke thisKey using {option down, command down}
                    delay thisLong
                end repeat
            else
                repeat with thisKey in {"1", "2"}
                    keystroke thisKey using {option down, command down}
                    delay thisLong
                end repeat
            end if
            repeat with thisKey in {"a", theRotation as text, "s"} -- # {Select All, Rotate Direction, Save}
                keystroke thisKey using {command down}
                delay thisLong
            end repeat
            keystroke theMenuItemChecked as text using {option down, command down} -- # Resets the 'View' menu to the original view.
            delay thisLong
            keystroke "w" using {command down} -- # Close Window.
        end tell
    end repeat
end run
```

**Notes:**

- As this *script* uses **UI Scripting**, when run from **Automator** (or **Script Editor**), the running app must be added to **System Preferences** > **Security** & **Privacy** > **Accessibility** in order to *run* properly. Saved as an *application*, the saved application would need to be added.
- Also with **UI Scripting**, the value of the `delay` *commands* may need to be changed for use on your system (and or additional `delay` *commands* added as appropriate, although in the case additional `delay` *commands* should not be needed). It should go without saying however test this on a set of a few document first to make sure the value set for `thisLong` works on your system. On my system this worked as coded.
- When using **UI Scripting** in this manner, once the task has started, one must leave the system alone and let it finish processing the files. Trying to multi-task will only set focus away from the task at hand and cause it to fail.
- If you need to rotate more then one time, add additional `theRotation as text,` to:

  ```
    repeat with thisKey in {"a", theRotation as text, "s"} -- # {Select All, Rotate Direction, Save}
  ```

  Example:

  ```
    repeat with thisKey in {"a", theRotation as text, theRotation as text, "s"}
  ```

Answer (score 1):

This python script will rotate by 90º clockwise all pages of any PDFs given as arguments, saving the result to a new file with "+90" appended to the filename.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# coding=utf-8
# Produces new PDF file with all pages rotated by 90 degrees.

import sys
import os
from Quartz import PDFDocument
from CoreFoundation import NSURL

if __name__ == '__main__':

    for filename in sys.argv[1:]:
        filename = filename.decode('utf-8')
        shortName = os.path.splitext(filename)[0]
        outFilename = shortName + "+90.pdf"
        pdfURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath_(filename)
        pdfDoc = PDFDocument.alloc().initWithURL_(pdfURL)
        if pdfDoc:
            pages = pdfDoc.pageCount()
            for p in range(0, pages):
                page = pdfDoc.pageAtIndex_(p)
                existingRotation = page.rotation()
                newRotation = existingRotation + 90
                page.setRotation_(newRotation)

            pdfDoc.writeToFile_(outFilename)
```